# Achieve a strong consistent view

Tags: couchbase

I just started using couchbase and hoping to use it as my data store.

One of my requirements in performing a query that will return a certain field about **all** the documents in the store. This query is done once at the server startup. 
For this purpose I need all the documents that exist and can't miss any of them.
I understand that views in couchbase are eventually consistent but I still hope this query can be done (at the cost of performance).

Notes about my configurating:

- I have only one couchbase server instance (I dont need sharding or
  replication)
- I am using the java client (1.4.1)

What I have tried to do is saving my documents this way:

```
client.set(key, value, PersistTo.ONE).get();
```

And querying using:

```
query.setStale(Stale.FALSE);
```

Adding the PersistTo parameter caused the following exception:

```
Cause by: net.spy.memcached.internal.CheckedOperationTimeoutException: Timed out waiting for operation - failing node: <unknown>
  at net.spy.memcached.internal.OperationFuture.get(OperationFuture.java:167)
  at net.spy.memcached.internal.OperationFuture.get(OperationFuture.java:140)
```

So I guess I am actually asking 3 questions:

1. Is it possible to get the consistent results I need?
2. If so, is what I suggested the correct way of doing that?
3. How can I prevent those exceptions?

The mapping I'm using:

```
function (doc,meta) {
    if (doc.doc_type && doc.doc_type == "MyType" && doc.myField) {
        emit(meta.id,null);
    }
}
```

Thank you

Comment: How many documents are you trying to set, only the one? Provide your mapping code too.

Comment: Thanks for replying. I added the mapping to the question. Not sure what did you mean regarding the number of documents? I have more then one document

Comment: When you are setting documents are you setting one and then refreshing the view or are you setting thousands of docs?  You might be getting timeouts if you are hammering a single node with thousands of updates.

Comment: yeah, I'm hammering about 3000 items, and only after that I restart my application server which performs the query

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Is it possible to get the consistent results I need?

Yes it is possible to set Couchbase views to be consistent by setting the STALE flag to false as you've done.  However there are performance impacts with this, so dependent on your data size the query may be slow, if you are only going to be doing it once a day then it should be ok.

Couchbase is designed to be a distributed system comprising of more than node, it's not really suitable for single node deployments.  I have read (but can't find the link) that view performances are much better in larger clusters.

You are also forcing more of a sync processing model onto a system that shines with async requests, PersistTo is ok to use for some requests but not system wide on every call (personal opinion), it'll definitely throttle throughput and performance.

> If so, is what I suggested the correct way of doing that?

You say the query is done after your application server is running, is this once per day or more?  If once a day then your application should work (I'd consider upping the nodes ;)), if you have to do this query a lot and you are 'hammering' the node over and over with sets then I'd expect to see what you are currently experiencing.

> How can I prevent those exceptions?

It could be a variety of reasons, what are the specs of your computer, RAM,CPU,DISK?  How much ram is allocated to Couchbase, how much to your bucket, what % of the bucket ram is used?

I've personally seen this when I've hammered some lower end AWS instances on some not so amazing networks.  What version of Couchbase are you using?  It could be a whole variety of factors that and deserves to be a separate question.

Hope that helps!

EDIT regarding more information on the Stale = false parameter (from official docs)

http://docs.couchbase.com/couchbase-manual-2.2/#couchbase-views-writing-stale

> The index is updated before the query is executed. This ensures that any documents updated (and persisted to disk) are included in the view. The client will wait until the index has been updated before the query has executed, and therefore the response will be delayed until the updated index is available.

Comment: thank you for the detailed answer. one last thing to make sure I got it: using stale=false still won't cause the query to return items that are in the disk queue?

Comment: I added some additional info about the stale flag, so only items that are persisted will be indexed.

Comment: thanks, I now understand my current configuration isn't a perfect fit, I'll try making the appropriate adjustments.

Comment: Ok cool, good to hear, if this has answered your problems you could mark it as answered :)